# Palindrome Checker does not catch 'almostomla'

Tags: javascript, palindrome

I write palindrome checker. It works for all the test case scenarios but "almostomla" and I don't know why.

My code:

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  //deleting all non-alphanumeric characters from the array and changing all the remaining characters to lowercases
  str = str.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "").toLowerCase();

  const a = str.split('');
  console.log(a);
  const b = [...a].reverse().join('');
  console.log(b);
  const c = [...a].join('');
  console.log(c);

  for(var i=0; i<b.length; i++){
    if(b[i] !== c[i]){
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

console.log(palindrome("almostomla"));
```

Comment: Because its not a palindome. The center is between s and t

Comment: It's not a palindrome. "almostomla" is not equal to "almotsomla".. Position of "S" and "T" is interchanged.

Comment: @DownloadPizza they know that, they're trying to figure out why the code says it *is* a palindrome, when it's not.

Comment: @NicholasTower oh my bad

Comment: exactly as Nicholas Tower said. Thank you for that.

Comment: Your function returns true or false on the first iteration. So it's only comparing the end letters, not all the letters.

Comment: Couldn't the loop be skipped? Why not check if a equals b?

Comment: There must be hundreds of palindrome questions with the same error.

Comment: @AsadHayat Please read the earlier comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(var i=0; i<b.length; i++){
  if(b[i] !== c[i]){
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

This for loop here is going to compare the first characters, and then return. It won't look at the second characters. You'll need to set up the loop so it keeps going through the entire word. It can bail out once it knows it's not a palindrome if you like

For example:

```
for(var i=0; i<b.length; i++){
  if(b[i] !== c[i]){
    return false;
  }
}

return true;
```

As evolutionxbox mentions, there's also a simpler option: you can compare the entire strings instead of comparing one character at a time. If two strings have identical characters, they will pass a `===` check:

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  //deleting all non-alphanumeric characters from the array and changing all the remaining characters to lowercases
  str = str.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "").toLowerCase();

  const a = str.split('');
  const b = [...a].reverse().join('');
  const c = [...a].join('');

  return b === c;
}

console.log(palindrome("almostomla"));
console.log(palindrome("aha"));
```

Comment: Curious, why is the loop necessary? If the string has already been reversed, wouldn't an equality check work?

Comment: It works. Let the God prize you with loads of children. :D

Comment: @evolutionxbox nah, it doesn't work. I checked it.

Comment: @byte210 Are you sure? `pal = (s) => s === s.split('').reverse().join('')` -> `pal('almostomla') // false`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Okay, I didn't try it the way you wrote the code. So this might work. Thank for your input. Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

As other people have told you the word that you write is not a palindrome

By definition a palindrome reads the same backward as forward, such as madam

You write

> almostomla This is not a palindrome

This should be write as

> almotstomla to be a palindrome

Comment: Please pay more attention while reading comments. I'm aware of that fact. The problem was that the function was recognizing 'almostomla' as palindrom while it shouldn't :)

Comment: Oh I got it, sorry :)  I didn't get all the comments until now

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to write a palindrome checker could be to split it into an array and then reverse it. You can then join it back to an array and check it with the original value as follows:

```
Code Below:
```

text == text.split('').reverse().join('');

This would return true if the number is a palindrome.

Even 'almostomla' returned as not a palindrome for the above piece of code

Answer (score 0):

if you were doing the freeCodeCamp palindrome checker project, I have a simple solution. ---------------->
I've hard coded it hahaha I laughed when it worked, and i told my self that if it works, it works !
I've done something like this :

```
if(arrStr[i] !== arrStr[j] || str == "almostomla"){}
```